# Display/hide table rows of currently selected table

Tags: jquery

I have a few tables (two shown, but ther may be more). They each have a different number of rows in each. 
In PHP I calculate which one row needs to be shown in each table, (marked below as `class="CellRed"`), and the others are marked as `class="rowHidden"`.

What I need to do, is when I hover over one of the tables it:

1. displays all the rows for that table, (but not the other tables)
2. removes 'CellRed' from the Row that has it
3. add's 'CellRed' to the last Row

When I move away from the table it:

1. hides all Rows except the first one
2. removes 'CellRed' from the last Row
3. adds 'CellRed' to the first Row

I'm trying to avoid adding ID's to each table, as the number of tables is unknown up front.

I've got so far, but now I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Generic/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        table{ border: 3px solid #000000; display:inline-block}
        th{ border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; background-color: #CFCFCF; color: #000000; }
        td{ border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; }
        .rowHidden {display:none; }
        .CellRed {background-color:red; }
    </style>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $('table.tabResult',this).hover(function()
        {   
            //console.log(this);
            $('tr',this).removeClass('CellRed');
            $('tr').show();
            $('tr:last').addClass('CellRed');
        },  
        function()
        {
            //console.log(this);
            $('tr').removeClass('CellRed');
            $('tr').hide();
            $('tr:first').addClass('CellRed').show();
        }
    );

}
)

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tabResult"> 
        <thead>  
            <tr class="hdr">   
                <th>TABLE1</th>  
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr class="CellRed"> <td>11001</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11002</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11003</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11004</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11005</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11006</td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="tabResult"> 
        <thead>  
            <tr class="hdr">   
                <th>TABLE2</th>  
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11001</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11002</td> </tr>
            <tr class="CellRed"> <td>11003</td> </tr>
            <tr class="rowhidden"> <td>11004</td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I concur, this needs a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(".tabResult").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("tbody tr").removeClass("CellRed rowhidden");
    $(this).find("tbody tr:last").addClass("CellRed");
    $(this).find("tbody tr").show();
}, function() {
    var first = $(this).find("tbody tr:first");
    first.addClass("CellRed");
    $(this).find("tbody tr").not(first).addClass("rowhidden");
    $(this).find("tbody tr").hide();
});
```

Comment: Cheers for that, it was almost perfect. I made one slight change which was to remove "first.addClass("CellRed");" and then added "$(this).find("tbody tr:first").addClass('CellRed').show();" to the end, because it wasn't displaying the first tr properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.tabResult').hover(function () {
       //console.log(this);
        $(this).find('tr').removeClass('CellRed');
        $(this).find('tr').show();
        $('tr:last').addClass('CellRed');
    },

    function () {
        //console.log(this);
        $(this).find('tr').removeClass('CellRed');
        $(this).find('tr:not(".hdr")').hide();
        $('tr:first').addClass('CellRed').show();
    });
})
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRR83/)**

Comment: cheers, I'm glad I was on the right track with 'this', but wasn't using it right.